# MODULE_NOT_FOUND when building my monorepo

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, monorepo

I have a TypeScript monorepo with an API and a folder for common code. When running it with nodemon for regular dev work it runs completely fine. But when I build it, I run into an annoying MODULE_NOT_FOUND error...

```
Error: Cannot find module '@cas/common/src/Errors'
Require stack:
- mono-test\@app\api\build\src\config.js
- mono-test\@app\api\build\src\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mono-test\@app\api\build\src\config.js:7:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'mono-test\\@app\\api\\build\\src\\config.js',
    'mono-test\\@app\\api\\build\\src\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

This is my folder structure

```
@app
  - api
    - build
    - src
      - index.ts
      - ...
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
packages
  - common
    - build
    - src
      - Errors.ts // i don't have an index.ts in this package
    - .gitignore
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json in root folder

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./@app/api"
    },
    {
      "path": "./packages/common"
    }
  ]
}
```

api's package.json and tsconfig.json, respectively

```
{
  "name": "@user/api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/src/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cas/common": "^1.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
  }
}
```

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json", // root folder's tsconfig.json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../packages/common"
    }
  ]
}
```

common's package.json and tsconfig.json, respectively

```
{
  "name": "@cas/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json", // root folder's tsconfig.json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

I believe I have everything linked correctly... I ran npm install in @app/api to install common as a dependency and built the common package prior to building my api package. Still this annoying error keeps coming back.